# Spark mllib: Difference between implicitTrain and explicitTrain

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I tried using explicit train function for recommending products based on user preferences (derived preferences) and MSE for it is good enough for both training and test dataset. (lambda=0.01)

The same data when I use in trainImplicit the MSE increases to 20 times for both test and training dataset.(lambda=0.01, alpha=1.0)

Now I understand that these are different algos but how do I make a judgment if the implicit is working better than explicit or not?

Comment: what are your ratings values for explicit?
I ask because if you don't normalize and for instance you have ratings between 1-5, your square error for a given ratings is going to be between 0 and 16. Whereas with implicit feedback it's going to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: also, how do you go from explicit to implicit?
to me, with explicit, for each users you have a lot of unknown (product they didn't rate) then ratings for some product (even if ratings are 0-1). 
Whereas implicit, you have a lot of 0 and a couple 1

Answer (score 3):

Basically the difference between implicit and explicit train is that implicit is suppose to be used when you only have implicit actions related to that item in order to make the recommendation e.g. views, clicks, purchases, likes, shares etc. Whereas explicit is suppose to be used when you have explicit rates about the items that you want to recommend.
Now talking about the application of this algorithm in the field I got also the same situation as you when doing a movie recommendation system and I cannot explain why implicit got better results than explicit when training in explicit datasets. In my view MSE is a suitable measure of performance. And one thing that you can do is to review the implementation of spark mllib and try to understand why :). 
Sorry If I did not answer you at all.

Comment: "implicit got better results than explicit when training in explicit datasets" How did you measure this?
Also do you need ratings/preferences to be between 0-1 for implicit algo?

Comment: Sorry to ping you again but can you reply to that ^